# how to add option in the Action field

Tags: magento2, blocks, render-blocking

in my case i want to add more option inside a column 'Voir' fro example 'option2' in a grid created with block ,
like this:
[image]

but for now i have just 'Renouveler'

the function in the class \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Reorder\Renderer\Action is:

```
 public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        $this->_actions = [];
        if ($this->_salesReorder->canReorder($row->getId())) {
            $reorderAction = [
                '@' => [
                    'href' => $this->getUrl('sales/order_create/reorder', ['order_id' => $row->getId()]),
                ],
                '#' => __('Renouveler'),
            ];

            $this->addToActions($reorderAction);
        }
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'adminhtml_customer_orders_add_action_renderer',
            ['renderer' => $this, 'row' => $row]
        );
        return $this->_actionsToHtml();
    }
```

> and the column in the block is :

```
if ($this->_salesReorder->isAllow()) {
            $this->addColumn(
                'action',
                [
                    'header' => 'Action',
                    'filter' => false,
                    'sortable' => false,
                    'width' => '100px',
                    'renderer' => \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Reorder\Renderer\Action::class
                ]
            );
        }
```

> can anyone tell me how to do that option with a specifique link for it  'Voir' with the id of the row in question ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
reorderAction = [      
                    'view' => [
                        'href' => $this->getUrl('sales/order_create/reorder', ['order_id' => $row->getId()]),
                        'label' => __('View'),
                    ],
                    'renew' => [
                        'href' => $this->getUrl('sales/order_create/reorder', ['order_id' => $row->getId()]),
                        'label' => __('Renew'),
                    ],
                    'delete' => [
                        'href' => $this->getUrl('sales/order_create/reorder', ['order_id' => $row->getId()]),
                        'label' => __('Delete'),
                        'confirm' => [
                            'title' => __('Delete'),
                            'message' => __('Are you sure you want to delete this row ?'),
                        ],
                    ],
                ];
```

Comment: i have an error on this method below render () above ==>Undefined index: that happens on this function on ligne html inside foreach ==>   
        foreach ($actions as $action) {
            $attributesObject->setData($action['view']);
            $html[] = '<a ' . $attributesObject->serialize() . '>' . $action['#'] . '</a>';
            var_dump($html);
        }

Comment: this line is not related to my answer. please check , you doing something wrong

Comment: okay bro i will do my best